# sending data to same PHP page from Javascript, no AJAX or forms

Tags: php, javascript, forms, post

I have a php page with some functions to recieve POST data, with a page refresh, no AJAX.

Right now I have a form with hidden fields that contain my dynamic data that I send with JS like so: `document.my_form.submit();`

Is it possible to send the data without using a form?

Basically I want to send an array of URL's from a list with thumbnails, so my function loops over the list and pushes them in arrays.

Comment: It is extremely important for the purposes of web security that a POST cannot be sent via a simple URL.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more.. These pages are behind a login system anyway, but I DO have my register page the same way.

Comment: @Pointy I'd really be interested in you clarifying this claim. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022201/php-security-send-post-to-same-url-bad

Comment: I interpret it as follows: If a post stores data on the server, then a get should not do that too, since a simple reload of the url again would write to the server.

Comment: Things like `<img>` and `<script>` tags are allowed to have cross-domain URLs. If it were possible to make one of those URLs do a "POST" instead of a "GET" (in a way that the browser didn't know it was happening), then there'd be an unstoppable CSRF problem.

Answer (score 1):

2000 characters should be ok these days:

http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you can only POST data via AJAX or a form.

Answer (score 0):

you can use get instead of post, but it sounds like the url will get pretty messy. if you aren't opposed to ajax, i would be happy to elaborate on the answer.

Comment: mmm, GET is not really an option as I will go over the 256 character limit.

Comment: if the urls are the same, but with some id difference , you could just send the ids, and do the url construction on the server side.

Comment: good thinking, but unfortunately my URL's are a bit random. I'll keep with the form I guess..