# PHP Security: send POST to same URL = bad?

Tags: php, post, redirect

I had a response on a question yesterday about sending POST data to the same page with the [Post-Redirect-Get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    // prevent resending data
    header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}
```

Someone replied: [sending data to same PHP page from Javascript, no AJAX or forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016968/sending-data-to-same-php-page-from-javascript-no-ajax-or-forms)

> It is extremely important for the purposes of web security that a POST cannot be sent via a simple URL.

Now I would like to know what is wrong with this? I want to avoid using a separate page with the confirmation message, because it just breaks the user experience and from a design POV it is a no-go.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the person means when they say it's important for POST not be be sent via a "simple" URL.

Comment: here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016968/sending-data-to-same-php-page-from-javascript-no-ajax-or-forms Person has 26K reputation.

Comment: Reputation on SO doesn't mean all *that* much... (25K as of this writing) ;)

Comment: Off course, but I do better ask again init?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It is extremely important for the
>   purposes of web security that a POST
>   cannot be sent via a simple URL.

I think the person who said this might have misunderstood either you or web security.

There's nothing wrong with using the same URL for different request methods (`GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, `HEAD` etc). In fact, it's a very good idea.

Answer (score 1):

> It is extremely important for the purposes of web security that a POST cannot be sent via a simple URL.

I rather interpret this sentence that it should not be possible that a GET request on the same URL does not cause the same as a POST request. So checking for `$_REQUEST['submit']` instead of implicitly checking `$_POST['submit']` or `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` could be a violation.

Maybe the author did also mean that the form uses some one-time authentication token so that only authenticated requests are permitted.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the replier didn't think his response through. I would imagine he was thinking there would be some security issues by using $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], but I can't see how in this case.

As already mentioned, there is nothing wrong with letting the same URL handle different requests.

That said, I still seperate the confirmation message from the form. I see no reason as to why I shouldn't. Validation and error messages can still occur on the form view, but just letting a lot of conditions determine wether you should show the confirmation message, the form or error messages seems like (IMO) your'e getting a lot of messy code.